# should i sample different size data variables, until they all have the same size?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy.stats

my dataset has a column 'sales_method' with 3 values A B C but they have different counts of 7400 4900 2500... should i sample for the smaller categories until they all have 7400 entries? or should i sample the big ones for only 2500 rows ? i have other numbers to compare about like 'revenue'. and maybe it can be inclined to bigger size = bigger revenue. (so sample whole rows without permutation I'm assuming). this could be just to make numpy functions work, when they need input of the same sizes.

Comment: "*should i sample for the smaller categories until they all have 7400 entries? or should i sample the big ones for only 2500 rows ?*" That's not for us to say, nor on topic for this website.

Comment: i see, is because the data is not of the same size, so you're saying i need to use either method to match sizes, and then we can say? alrighty thanks  after all, i only have two more days to solve this question and submit the project ‍

Comment: My view is that oversampling is usually unnecessary, and the wrong tool for the job. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he

Comment: awesome, thank u, makes sense, they provide the same results, i hope i can use different sizes with numpy in my tasks.